# Rewriting a function to asynchronous function

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to rewrite a function to work asynchronously in order for a pop up to appear regardless of server side response time. The function:

```
  async GetAllItems(Items) {
    try {
        const response = await this.http.get<Items[]>(this.baseUrl + 'Items/Getall=' + items + '&SystemId=' + items).toPromise();
        return response;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

and this is the .html file:

```
<div *ngIf="All.lst_itm">
  <div *ngFor="let items of All.lst_itm">
        <mat-accordion>
            <mat-expansion-panel style=" width: 500px; background: black">
                <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport style="float: right;" itemSize="35" class="description">
                    <div *ngIf="A">{{items.ShowA}}</div>
                    <div *ngIf="B">{{items.ShowB}}</div>
                </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
                <br>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
        </mat-accordion>
    </div>
</div>
```

the error in chrome console:

```
InformationComponent.html:18 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lst_itm')
```

There is an error with 'lst_itm' but I do not understnad why the line `<div *ngIf="All.lst_itm"><div *ngIf="All.lst_itm">` doesn't fix it? what can I do? any additional information is required?

Comment: When you see the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'some_property')`, look to the left of the dot of `some_property`. Whatever is there is `undefined`

Comment: Thanks, this is important, I am trying to define the variable like this `ngOnInit() {this.All.lst_itm = [];}` but the error still persist. How it is still undefined if i just did define it as empty array?

Comment: `this.All.lst_itm = []` would make the `lst_itm` an array, not `All`

Comment: Note also you will want to use `*ngIf="All.lst_itm.length"` instead of `*ngIf="All.lst_itm"` if dealing with arrays, as `[]` is truthy

Comment: I0_ol you are correct, I solved this specific error but now I get additional 'undefined properties' for everything that is related to `All` variable since I declared it to be empty, is there any way for the pop up window to appear with no errors and when the response from server is ready then make the relevant data appear? I can provide more code if needed.

Comment: Anything I can try??

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular so the amount of help I can offer is very limited.